# Number decimal issue

Tags: javascript

I am having problem that is not calculating the total correctly.

I am getting total value is `24`, I am expecting `25.60000`

What did I do wrong?

Example:

```
var a = "12.80000"; //Set as string deliberately
var b = "12.80000";

var total = 0;
total += roundAmount(parseInt(a), 5);
total += roundAmount(parseInt(b), 5);

console.log(total); 

function roundAmount(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
}
```

Comment: well I doubt you want parseInt.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are chopping off the decimal with parseInt, you want parseFloat.

```js
var a = "12.80000"; //Set as string deliberately
var b = "12.80000";

var total = 0;
total += roundAmount(parseFloat(a), 5);
total += roundAmount(parseFloat(b), 5);

console.log(total); 

function roundAmount(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
}
```

You are not going to get the extra trailing zeros in the output, if you want them, you need to use toFixed(5) when you output it.

Comment: Ahh I see, but I am expecting `25.60000`, not `25.6`

Comment: As my comment says, `console.log(total.toFixed(5));`

Comment: Why to parse a number that will be cast to String anyway?

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT I am just answering the code to show why it was truncated, I did not want to alter what the OP was doing in the rest of the code.

Comment: You can remove the second argument to `parseFloat`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: @epascarello egg on my face, I believe the expression is. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're converting a floating point number to an integer with parseInt() so your computer stores "12.8000" as an integer type (i.e. 12). Try using the parseFloat() function instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your parseInt() functions are rounding the numbers to 12 before they are added, instead use parseFloat().
This works for me:

```
var a = "12.80000"; //Set as string deliberately
var b = "12.80000";

var total = 0;
total += roundAmount(parseFloat(a,10), 5);
total += roundAmount(parseFloat(b,10), 5);

console.log(total); 

function roundAmount(value, decimals) {
    return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
}
```